# Best practice to keep common steps of cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using cucumber-watir-webdriver with for automation purposes. I have the following directory structure:

```
|features
 -|feature1
 --|1.feature
 --|step_definitions
 ---|1.rb
 -feature2
 --|2.feature
 --|step_definitions
 ---|2.rb
```

and so on. I need to know what is best practice to reduce redundancy in `1.rb` and `2.rb`.
`feature1` and `feature2` are completely different so I cannot combine both in one directory.
Also there is some part where feature line is same but execution in steps is different so it will create ambiguity if they are together.

I need to know if there is some part common in `1.rb` and `2.rb` where should I put it is there best practice to keep common step definitions.

Comment: what do you need?? Like "check for database entry" is in both features but databases they check is different I don't want to mix them and complicate things. But steps like "Given I logged in" are same so I want to put their step definitions somewhere combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber only searches for step definitions in current or following directories.
So we can not have common step definitions directory or file below two feature directories,
I found one solution to this as

```
|features
 -|feature1
 --|1.feature
 --|step_definitions
 ---1.rb
 -feature2
 --|2.feature
 --|step_definitions
 ---2.rb
 -|common_steps.rb <-- keep common steps in here
```

now to load this step definition add

```
 require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../common_steps.rb"
```

in your 1.rbs.
also you can have longer directory structure then you can keep     common_steps.rb  file in every such directory containing common steps of following features and you can require previous common_steps.rb file with--

```
 require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../common_steps.rb"
```

this code. 
This will keep your directory structure and step_definition files clean

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to separate out your features into individual directories, but it's best to keep your `*_step.rb` files together in one `step_definitions` directory under the `features` directory. You can put steps common to both features into a `common_steps.rb` file (even better would be something like `login_steps.rb` and `test_data_creation_steps.rb` instead of `common_steps.rb`).

To translate that into the same style directory structure diagram as in your question, I'd suggest the following:

```
|features
 -|feature1
 --|1.feature
 -feature2
 --|2.feature
 -|step_definitions
 --|1.rb
 --|2.rb
 --|common_steps.rb <-- put your common steps in here
```

Comment: Thanks man but I have just one doubt will those step definitions will be loaded in case I run 
    "cucumber /features/feature1/1.feature" 
if there is tree 2-3 level deep and I want to run specific feature like
"cucumber /features/feature1/feature1.1/1.1.feature" then will cucumber autoload /feature/step_definition

Comment: That's incorrect, they won't be loaded. You'll have to tell Cucumber where to look: `cucumber -r features features/feature1/1.feature`. By default, step definitions and support code are looked for in the containing directory of the specified feature(s) and its subdirs.

Comment: @jbpros I thought so, but the way you are suggesting will also load 2.rb if I'm running 1.feature I don't want that

Comment: @UdaySwami be more specific in the `-r` path then :) `cucumber -r features/step_definitions/1.rb features/feature1`