# Multiple instance of browser when using common steps in Cucumber Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have an extremely simple test scenario set up, which basically opens a browser and does some navigation and it all worked fine. When I separated some of the steps out into a common_steps file, multiple instances of the browser (4x) were opening which in turn failed the test because the elements could not be found.

When I copied the common steps back into the original file, the test runs fine. I'm a bit confused as I don't understand how it opens multiple browsers when there are no extra steps or lines in the feature file to tell it to do so.

This is an example of how I approached it. I know the code is a little untidy and it requires things like a global wait and such but that will be done after I fix this issue, and it is a work in progress.

**Scenario**

```
Scenario Outline: Navigate through Chrome
Given I opened the home page of "<homeUrl>"
Then navigated to my favourite site of "<myFavUrl>"
Then navigated to the Dojo page
When the full catalog was displayed
And the performance option was selected

Examples:
|homeUrl                        |myFavUrl                                   |
|https:\\www.google.co.uk       |https://www.ministryoftesting.com/         |
```

**Constants File**.

```
 public class Constant {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Constant() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public WebDriver setChromeDriver() {
        if(driver == null) {

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            return driver;
        }else
            return driver;

    }

}
```

**Common steps file**.

```
public class CommonSteps extends Constant {


    @Given("^I opened the home page of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void navigateToHomePage(String url) throws Throwable{
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Then("^navigated to my favourite site of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void navigateToFavourite(String myFavSite) throws Throwable{
        driver.get(myFavSite);
    }

    //To be used in a separate scenario
    @Given("^I opened the home page of Ministry Of Testing$")
    public void quickLinkToMot() throws Throwable{
        driver.get("https://www.ministryoftesting.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

**Specific Steps File**

```
    @Then("^navigated to the Dojo page$")
    public void navigateToDojo() throws Throwable{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
        WebElement djLinkParent = driver.findElement(By.id("navbar-collapse"));
        WebElement djLink = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(djLinkParent.findElement(By.linkText("Dojo"))));
        djLink.click();
    }

    @When("^the full catalog was displayed$")
    public void displayFullCatalog() throws Throwable{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
        WebElement fullCatBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[class='btn btn-xl btn-home']")));
        fullCatBtn.click();
    }

    @And("^the performance option was selected$")
    public void selectPerformance() throws Throwable{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
        WebElement pBtnParent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='cat cat2']"));
        WebElement perfLink = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pBtnParent.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/dojo/lessons?topic=performance']"))));
        perfLink.click();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Jd_Daniels, how are you launching/navigating the new site - In a same window or in the new browser window?

Comment: What is the user of `setChromeDriver()` method in the Constant class? Where are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

The construction of your project is not the proper one. Constructions can vary but when you need to use BDD Cucumber then that means that you want its concept in your project. Then you need to follow the state-of-the-art techniques to do so. Please take a look below.

**SOLUTION:**

I think the solution to your problem is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910763/best-practice-to-keep-common-steps-of-cucumber).

It tells you how to create the architecture in your project because I believe your architecture is wrong.

I think is what you are looking for.